# Trying to inject a mocked instance in a test class with autofac, but the container is injecting the same instance in other test classes

Tags: c#, mocking, autofac, functional-testing

I'm trying to resolve a handler to my test using autofac, then i'm injecting a mocked instance of it in that way:

```
_mockedHandlerInstance = new TestHandler(_repository.Object, _mediator.Object, _logger.Object);

containerBuilder.RegisterInstance(_mockedHandlerInstance).As<HandlerToProcess>();
```

The same container is created in a TestBase class that is inherited in other test classes, but when i try to use something related with the `HandlerToProcess` the container return the same instance that i've created and mocked before in the class above.

So, what i need is to create a specific mock of this handle for each class and use autofac to inject them, do you guys know anyway to do this?

The `TestBase` class just initialize the container and register a few asseblies:

```
Settings.LoadConfigContext("configurationSettings");

EffortProviderFactory.ResetDb();


_containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

var assemblies = new Assembly[]
{
    typeof(AppModule).Assembly,
    typeof(Repository).Assembly,
};

_containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new AutofacModule(assemblies));
```

I'm also using Effort, but i don't think this could cause the problem.

Comment: Can you share `TestHandler` class, as well as calling code in `TestBase` and other classes?

Comment: I shared the main parts of the TestBase class, but i think this is happening cause the others classes with the same inheritance are resolving the TestHandler as the mocked Instance.

Comment: Its very hard to understand your question. Try to share more code. Your base class relevant parts, derived class with some test methond etc. Do not omit class declaration in your code snippets, it will be much easer to get the whole image.

Comment: And what the test framework is used?